# Dividing elements in a list with the following element?

Tags: python, list

Let's say I have this list:

```
myList = [500,50,2]
```

And I want to divide each element with the following element, like this: `500 / 50 = 10 / 2 = 5`

Output: `5`

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
def keep_divide(numbers):
    # get the first number
    result = numbers[0]
    # use for loop to keep dividing
    for i in range(1,len(numbers)):
        result /= numbers[i]
    return result

numbers = [500,50,2]
print(keep_divide(numbers))
```

Answer (score 6):

[`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) is perfect for this:

```
from functools import reduce

li = [500, 50, 2]
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x / y, li))
```

Though you may want to make sure that no element is zero beforehand, or catch an exception to handle it:

```
try:
    print(reduce(lambda x, y: x / y, li))
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("There was a zero in the list")
```

With an explicit function:

```
from functools import reduce

li = [500, 50, 2]

def div(a, b):
    return a / b

print(reduce(div, li))
```

With [`operator.truediv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truediv):

```
import operator
from functools import reduce

li = [500, 50, 2]
print(reduce(operator.truediv, li))
```

Comment: What if I want to make it a function and not use lambda? or is lambda better for this?

Comment: DeepSpace, I added an option for the divide-by-zero, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @slothie I added 2 options that don't use lambdas